# Did I screw up when imaging luks partition?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks, disk-image

Background: https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2249654?noredirect=1

Ok, so when I imaged the drive it was unlocked and I only imaged the luks partition (IE. only the luks part of the drive and not the unlocked part of the drive), now when restored I cannot mount the drive - "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock". Is this salvageable?

I've tried imaging to a separate drive, losetup, mount, mounting the image,etc., everything comes up with errors. When I unlock the drive I can open the drive, (input password) but any attempts to mount it will result in errors. I've even tried to DD the unlocked partition to another drive, no luck.

Is this in any way salvageable?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the rule here is one topic per problem. If you have additional information to share, edit your original post, but don't open additional ones.

Comment: Understood, however, I thought that the topics were different enough to warrant a new topic. Will keep that in mind for next time. Please feel free to merge topics if necessary. Still having a problem with this btw.

Comment: Guessing it's fucked...? Does this img contain any information at all? Done some searching but couldn't find info.